# Can Monsters with class levels take Monster Feats instead of Regular Feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, feats

I'm designing a monster which through virtue of high intelligence and me being evil, that has 13 class levels.

However, I also want to bump up the save DC on its special ability. The feat "Ability Focus" will do just that, however it is a monster feat and not a regular feat, so I do not know if it is technically legal to take a monster feat when the creature would normally get a feat for her class levels.

I'll probably do it either way, but I want to know if I'll have to explain it as GM fiat or not.

Comment: I know it's not an answer, but you're probably worrying about it a bit too much.  Monster building is more art than science or law.

Comment: @C. Ross - I agree, I'm more asking the question for when everything is said and done, the players will say "well how did she...", and I just want to know if I'll have to say I fluffed it or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes.** According to [the Pathfinder SRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/monsterFeats.html), even player characters can take monster feats if they happen to qualify:

> **Monster Feats**
>
> Most of the following feats apply specifically to monsters, although some player characters might qualify for them (particularly Craft Construct).

Comment: I forgot Craft Construct was in Monster Manual/Bestiary.  It still doesn't make sense.